# In refinery CMS "Settings" tab not occur in application admin

Tags: refinerycms

In Refinery CMS ,
On the settings tab in the back end not present.
Is anybody facing the same problem ?

In the demo application for refinery CMS the "Setting" tab is present.
When I created new project using refinery.
there is no tab "Setting".

Please tell me , How to enable that tab or is there any gem dependency ?

I am stuck with this only. :(

Please reply asap.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Hiya, are you sure you have right permissioning and refinery is set-up correctly and please try emailing this email: refinery-cms@googlegroups.com , hope it helps, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiya  so just to share with wider audience the answer from refinery guys & here it is:

hope that email helped you

Philip Arndt : quote

to refinery-cms

Yes refinerycms-settings is no longer included by default.
It's now a gem packed separately to the rest http://rubygems.org/gems/refinerycms-settings

Cheers

Comment: Hey thanks , I got it, But how should i integrate it with my application ?. Is there any configuration settings ??

Comment: Hiya, Cool, in the refinery blog there is a document for integrating it with **existing** application, remember the cool thing is you can override the files and debug it for your existing application integration, hope it helps, cheers

Comment: hey guys , This is just for people to help. The feature for "settings" tab not available in latest version of refinerycms. If want to do the configuration changes it will be in "configuration/initializers/refinery/" Thanks.

Comment: For complete installation instructions see https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-settings

Comment: What a dumb decision. It's my 3rd refinery site. Just wasted half-an-hour to discover that the settings is on a separate gem. And I'm still trying to find out how to change the name of the site. The bootstrap of a refinery site is much worst than it was, it is was already far from great.

Answer (score 1):

This is just for people to help. 
The feature for "settings" tab not available in latest version of refinerycms. 
If want to do the configuration changes it will be in "configuration/initializers/refinery/"
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry , One thing missed , also there one gem available "refinerycms-settings-initializer"

Comment: For complete installation instructions see https://github.com/wikyd/refinerycms-settings-initializer